# Unable install webconsole in ServiceMix 4.5.3

Tags: apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix, web-console

I deleted Cache and tmp directory of my serviceMix. 
 I'm trying to reinstall webconsole on using 
   features:install webconsole. I'm getting following error

Error executing command: Manifest not present in the first entry of the zip mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.metatype/1.0.4

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a known problem with reorganization of maven repositories which caused some troubles. Please make sure that your local repository does not contain malformed JAR file (it happens sometimes with various gateways which redirects you to login page), then reconfigure repositories in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg and make entry

```
 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central
```

First in list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally it worked for me. As you suggested i cleared entire repository and ran servicemix, then tried to install webconsole. It is successfull. I think it is issue with the corrupted jar. If it happens next time I'll add maven url and let you know.

Comment: If this helped you please click mark my reply as proper fix.